# Adding fields to Contacts Pop Up

Tags: contacts

I have tried searching for this but not sure what it's called?

Is it possible to alter the fields that display in the pop-up you get if you hover over a contact? We want to add some of the custom fields here if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Administer - Customize - Profiles, it's the one called Summary Overlay.

Comment: Should add its under the "reserved profiles tab"